# Issues with current parent page along with redirect on form submit into _blank window

Tags: javascript, java, php, forms

The following code I put together works the following way:

1) On PAGE1.php a product listing page, a user clicks the BuyNow button and it triggers a form to pass the item variables to a new page via "_blank" which is on INVOICE.php where the invoice is created on screen and displayed..

2) The original Parent page PAGE1.php of which features the product listing and BuyNow button refreshes itself on form submit (not sure how as I am not specifically requesting it to do so).

3) I require the form on PAGE1.php to trigger the invoice "_blank page" INVOICE.php page as it currently does but then also have the original Parent window PAGE1.php also redirect to say PAGE3.php or any other custom page url such as UPSELL.php but not simply refresh the original PAGE1.php page..

I have tried different methods but multiple functions stopped the required variables passing through to the "_blank" page..

Hopefully someone can help me end this week on this task completion..

Thank you!

```
<form name="fwrdform" class="d-flex justify-content-left" method="post" action="http://EXAMPLE.COM/addtocart">

  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity" aria-label="Search" class="form-control" style="width: 65px">

  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$product->id}}">

  <input type="hidden" width="100" height="40" value="submit" src="/buynow.png" alt="Buy Now" onMouseOut="this.src='/buynow.png'" onMouseOver="this.src='/buynow.png'">

  <a href="http://EXAMPLE.com/checkout" target="_blank"
    value="submit" onClick="document.forms['fwrdform'].submit();"><img border="0" src="http://EXAMPLE.com/buynow.png" width="100" height="auto">
  </a>

<br><br>
```

Comment: Mirakurun thank you for the posting tweak.. Very appreciated!

Comment: Not that sure I understood your aiming, but I think, probably, you should use the `window.open()` method to open the `'_blank page'` and then you could get the `URL` from that page and use it in the main page which will redirect to that `URL`.